# How to transpile node_module dependencies coming as ES module?

Tags: javascript, webpack

A dependency package that I'm using only has `module` and `main` as entry points. By default, the webpack version I'm using resolves to module entry point first. If I set `resolve.mainFields` to `main` in webpack configuration, I might affect other dependencies that were being resolved by 'browser' entry point by default.

So, the question is, how can I transpile a dependency like that and have it bundled in my bundle in ES5?

Comment: still not good idea to bundle dependencies with your package.

Comment: My package is a web application so it make sense to bundle all dependencies in it

Answer (score 0):

Some package writers distributes their ES6 sources, some other don't.

If you can figure out what "modern JavaScript syntax" the dependency is using, In general, the standard format for distributing a module is called **CJS** or **Common JS**.

If the author of the package you are trying to use did not export **CJS** from it's bundle (in 99% they do), then you don't need to transpile anything.

What do you mean by "the other ones"?

Be sure to import the right sources.

Comment: The package x contains a umd file referenced in main field and a es2015 entry point referenced in module field of package.json. 
The packages y, z might use browser resolve by default. If I set webpack to resolve to main by default, x will work but y and z might not (in this case y and z are lot of dependencies and not just two. And I dont like the idea of testing the application manually to see if any dependency that is now resolved as main fails. Because main is supposed to be for node, and the application is web)

Comment: `main` is not supposed to be for node. `main` is the entrypoint by default for all npm packages. Read https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main

Comment: browser is browser specific, main is a general entry point and finally module is a newer format used in case the bundler works with ES modules (webpack does). The point is if some dependency other than x uses browser as entry point because main is used just for node, then I have a problem there

Comment: I am using webpack 4, module and main. You should not worry about if the ESM version is used. Webpack will try to use the ESM build and if it fail, it will use the main. ESM is experimental, I've been exporting both, ESM (using rollup) and CJS, webpack can handle that without additional setup

Comment: Yo mean with a loader?

Comment: No, loader are another concept of Webpack and that's totally unrelated.